# 1 bad phpfpm pool.d config causes disaster

Tags: php-fpm

I noticed that if a pool config in `pool.d` has a bad path, then all the pools won't start when doing `systemctl start php7.0-fpm.service` - is there a way to make phpfpm gracefully continue?

I've tried to research phpfpm config details but I can't find anything related to a graceful continue if 1 pool is bad

Answer (score 1):

php-fpm has a test flag you can use to test config files

```
  --test
  -t             Test FPM configuration file and  exit  If  called  twice
                 (-tt), the configuration is dumped before exiting.
```